# WPF: 3D cube with rounded corners

Tags: wpf, 3d, cube

is it possible create a cube with rounded corners in WPF? I found many examples that easily create cubes with hard edges but none with rounded ones. One possible solution would be a pre-rendered object, but that's not easy and controls to be put on the sides must be transformed separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a 3D modelling package to create the object and then export it to XAML.

There are plenty of free packages out there, or expensive ones with free trials, that should have this functionality.

Comment: It would probably be possible to construct it programatically; that could be fun!

Comment: @Zakalwe - Getting the normals on the corners would be "fun", which is why I suggested using a modelling app.